# how to reload a page with jQuery with the selected option in dropdown and also displaying the option id in the address?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a doubt on, how to reload a page while selecting on a option in a drop down box in jQuery? If I select an option in dropdown, that option's id should be changed and displayed on the current web address. Could anyone help me on this issue?

The codings for that issue is as follows:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#loading').css('visibility','hidden');
    jQuery(function(){
        $("#filter_categories").change(function(){
            window.location='http://example.com/index.php?option=com_user_advert&view=category&id=2&Itemid=106';
        });
    });
    });


jQuery.ajax({ 
                  url: url, 
                  type: 'POST', 
                  data: datas, 
                 // dataType: "json", 
                  success: function(data) { 
                            var total = data.substring(0,data.indexOf('##'));
                            if(data){
                                  if(total>0){
                                    jQuery("#list").html(data.substring(data.indexOf('##')+2));
                                    jQuery('#loading').css('visibility','hidden');
window.location='http://example.com/index.php?option=com_user_advert&view=category&id='+jQuery("#filter_categories").val()+"&Itemid=106";
                                    //ajaxCall();
                                  }
                                 else{
                                 jQuery("#list").html("");
                                 alert('No result found');
                                 return false;
                                 } 
                            }
                    }
            });
    location.reload();
}
</script>
```

Is this correct? Or help me to find the correct way. Thank you.

Comment: can you be little more clear with your question..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my understanding of your question I have created some code...

```
$("#dropdown").change(function () {
        var id = this.value;
        var URL = window.location.href;
        var domainremove = URL.split('?');
        var urlstrings = domainremove .split('&');
        var replacement = "myid="+id;
        var final_URL;
    for(var i = 0 ; i < urlstrings.length ; i++){
        if(urlstrings.indexOf("myid=")>=0)
            final_URL[i]+= replacement  //rewriting URL
        else
            final_URL+=urlstrings[i];
    }
        window.location.href = final_URL;
       //call ajax if u want
    });
```

Hope it helps

Comment: yes @theRoot, you are correct about my question. You are exactly understood my question. Thank you for your exact correct answer.